# SSH Key Authentification with users in group

Tags: linux, ssh, private-key

My problem is the login via ssh with key authentification. This work quite well so far: The login with e.g. putty to the server works. The public key is in the ~/.ssh directory stored and the private key is the right.

But if I add a user to the group of the user I would like to login, the login is not possible so far. I see an password prompt and am encouraged for enter password for the user, but my private key is not used anymore. After I had enter the right password, it works as well.

If I remove the user from the /etc/group again, the user is able again to login with key.

Only If at least one user in the group of the user, the ssh key login does not work anymore.

If anyone has a suggestion und would post this here, it would be very nice.

Regards

Sven

Answer (score 4):

Check the permissions of .ssh directory and the authorized_keys file.  If you have multiple users in the group and the directory is group writable, the keys are not used anymore. You can see it on the server from /var/log/auth.log where the sshd agent should report something like "Authentication refused: bad ownership or modes"

The .ssh directory should have permissions 700 (only user can read, write, and execute). For files 600 (only user can read and write) are the best permissions. In some implementations also the home directory can't be group writable.

The reason for all this is that if the files are writable by group, anyone in that group could add their own key and login as you.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.

The permissions as follows, but is still doesn't work. I have changed the permissions for the directory (recursively) and the user added to the group (I expected the persmissions to be the problem already): 
drwx------ 2 git git 4096 Feb  2 19:01 .
drwxrwx--- 6 git git 4096 Feb  2 19:01 ..
-rwx------ 1 git git  790 Feb  2 19:01 authorized_keys

Comment: The parent directory (..) seems to have write bit still set. Try changing that to be only writable by user (and possibly it's parent also all the way to root).